# Betta fish: girl or boy?

Tags: fish, betta, gender-differentiation

My fish, Dylan Marie, is believed to be a girl. However, I’ve been noticing some bubble nests in her bowl! (Just for your information, the bowl is bigger than in the pictures and she does seem to enjoy her bowl. I also clean her bowl regularly), so the question here is: is Dylan a boy or girl? She is about four to five months old. Thank you!

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Welcome to Pets Stack Exchange :) Generally, a bowl is not a great home for a fish. Betta's are tropical fish which need heat and filtration to ensure that they can live long healthy lives. Check out [this question and answer](https://pets.stackexchange.com/questions/5865/how-can-i-help-my-betta-who-is-laying-at-the-bottom-of-his-tank) for more information.

Answer (score 3):

Based on those pics I think you won't get a definite answer here. 
But just from the looks of you betta I would actually say it is male:

- It's still pretty colourful
- It's making nests
- The fins are not that short...

But the best way to check if it is a female is by looking for a white spot (egg spot) between the front/side fins and their bottom fins. 
A few other steps to do identification are mentioned here: https://www.wikihow.com/Determine-the-Sex-of-a-Betta-Fish

Keep in mind there are also short finned betta's: betta plakat. 
A pet shop once sold me one of these saying it was female. 
After a couple months it got bigger, more colourful and also became aggressive towards my other male betta (spoiler: it did not end well for my other betta :-( ).

Answer (score 1):

She looks like a female to me. Although I’m not an expert, she has a shorter, stubbier body, shorter fins, and female bettas can blow bubble nests too. If you want to be sure, could you attach a picture of her flaring. The difference is more noticeable then!

Comment: I don't know if this answer is correct, but if you add some supporting references I would be able to tell. I always try to upvote answers with supporting references.

Answer (score 0):

Fin length shows it is a male .  Although not as long as the usual commercial fish. The young need to be separated at an early age, about one inch length as they start fighting and nipping fins. This one was not separated soon enough , maybe it was 1 and 1/4 inch and had lost some fin. Females do not make bubble nests. I have raised them and it is a hassle for an amateur to maintain a few dozen individual containers for males. I sold the remaining "females" to pet shops , likely with 10 to 20 % males.

Comment: If a brood of bettas is raised in one tank , all will have short fins.