# Is my Betta too thin or sick?

Tags: health, fish, betta

I recently became a responsible betta owner. I never knew how wrong I was about them. My butterfly betta, Olaf eats very well but has a lump on one side and is less active today. He usually swims very actively and explores his tank or watches me work. He eat freeze dried blood worms, bugs or brine shrimp twice daily. He is in a 5 gallon tank alone with moss balls and mat, bio  stone, resting leaf and a castle cave. Temp is 80 degrees. Using bubble sponge filter. Live plants are on order and a floating log.[fish bump[image: ][1]]

Comment: The lump could be his swim bladder but I’m not sure.

Comment: This will not fully answer your question, but will help https://pets.stackexchange.com/questions/5865/how-can-i-help-my-betta-who-is-laying-at-the-bottom-of-his-tank